# Why doesn't the last cout display the array

Tags: c++

If i try to input lets say 9,-9, 9.9, -9.9, the last array cout doesn't display the array and the return value isn't 0 its 3221226356. The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double unos;
    int N = 1;
    double *arr = new double [N];
    int counter = 0;
    
    //unesi arr (prekida se ako 0)
    do{
        cin >> unos;
        if (unos != 0){
            arr[counter] = unos;
            counter ++;
        }
    }while(unos != 0);
    
    
    //isprintaj arr
    cout << "Array na unosu: "<< endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to make a dynamic array that can hold positive and negative decimal and whole numbers. It is just the beginning stage of the program but i can't proceed if I don't fix this.

Comment: Since you set ```N=1```, your array can't hold more than one item. Actually, ```arr``` is not a dynamic array since its size can't increase over time. Use ```std::vector``` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a "dynamic array" since it never resizes. As it is, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) by reading/writing outside of the bounds of `arr`.

You could achieve this by allocating a new larger array as necessary, copying over the contents of `arr`, destroying the original array, and then having `arr` point to the new array.

```
    do{
        if (counter >= N) {
            int new_N = N * 2;
            double *new_arr = new double[new_N];
            std::copy(arr, arr + N, new_arr);
            delete[] arr;
            arr = new_arr;
            N = new_N;
        }

        cin >> unos;
        if (unos != 0){
            arr[counter] = unos;
            counter ++;
        }
    }while(unos != 0);
```

But you'd be better off just using [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which handles all this for you.

Comment: You're right. I had the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: Yet another reason to use `std::vector`. Because if Chris messed that up, what chance do us mere mortals have to get it right?

Comment: Oh good. I've been placed on a pedestal. No chance I'll fall off of that. ;)